# Voice Assistant enable text selection in samsung devices

Tags: android, voice, assistant

As per the google's accessibility support document(https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6378148?hl=en), we should use UrlSpan and local context menu to detect the clickable span in talkback mode. Samsung devices don't have talkback app by default so we should download the app to avail this feature. Please share other options to enable local context menu in samsung devices